# iPhone apps UI layout issue when running on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autolayout

I have an application targeted only to iPhone.
Every UI is displaying perfect when I run it on iPhone.
But When I run it on iPad retina, some space of UI is cutting off from right side.
This cutted off space is shown with red in attached screenshot.
Can some one tell me what is the problem of UI when it's running on iPad?

some details:
XCode Version - 6.3
project deployment target - iOS 8
Uses storyboard.

[image]

**EDIT1:**
I mean this space is out of the edges of the screen. Like UI's width widen to some pixels.

Comment: please provide more information on how your layout is done. If you are using auto layout then please check your constraints.

Comment: It turns out there wasn't used any autolayout, That's why UI is behaving like this, UI is targeted to only one kind screen dimension. I need to fix this problem, it was moved to me from another developer